# How to compute sum of sum of gcd of factor pairs of a number upto a large number efficiently?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, gcd-and-lcm, computational-mathematics, arithmetic-functions

Define
$$f(n)=\sum_{d|n}gcd(d,\frac{n}{d})$$
$$F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^xf(n)$$ for natural numbers d,n and x.

I would like to know if there is some simplified form of $F(x)$ in terms of arithmetic functions, or atleast some computationally feasible form for large $x$.($x$ is of the order $10^{15}$ or higher).

A brute force approach is not efficient because of the $d|n$.Exchanging the summations is a slight improvement.But even after that I can't evaluate $F(x)$ for $x>10^7$ within reasonable time for which I believe a total mathematical algorithmic change is needed.

How can we manipulate the given expression so that the computation is reasonably fast?

EDIT:I just found out this is one of the Project Euler problems-problem no. 530

Comment: Actually we dont even need n, since there is a sum over n too while defining F(x).

Comment: Perhaps you can precompute the values of $f(n)$ and $F(x)$.

Comment: No idea whether this is of any use. But for squarefree $n$, $f(n)$ is just the number of divisors of $n$.

Comment: No idea whether this is of any use, but if we define
$$c(p,i):=\begin{cases}
2p^{\tfrac{i+1}{2}}&\text{ if }i\equiv1\pmod{2}\\
p^{\tfrac i2+1}+p^{\tfrac i2}&\text{ if }i\equiv0\pmod{2}\
\end{cases},$$
then for the function $S(n,k)$ defined by the recursion
$$S(n,k):=\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\log_{p_k}x\rfloor}\frac{c(p_k,i)-2}{p_k-1}S\big(\lfloor\tfrac{x}{p_k^i}\rfloor,k+1\big),$$
and $S(0,k)=0$ and $S(1,k)=1$, we have
$$S(x,1)=\sum_{n=1}^x\sum_{d\mid n}\gcd(d,\tfrac dn)=F(x).$$
Here $p_k$ denotes the $k$-th prime, starting from $p_1=2$.

Answer (score 4):

PARTIAL ANSWER:
Here is an alternative formula for $F(x)$:
$$F(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{x}}g_x(k)k$$
where
$$g_x(k) = |\{ (a,b) : abk^2 \le x, \ \gcd(a,b)=1 \}|$$

*proof:*

For a fixed $x>0$, consider the following set
$$I_x=\{ (k, d, n) \ : \ k=\gcd(d, n/d), \ \ d|n,\ \ n \le x\}$$
Then your $F(x)$ is just
$$F(x)= \sum_{(k,d,n) \in I_x} k$$
Let's study how this set $I_x$ is made.

First of all, note that for all $(k,d,n) \in I_x$ you have that $k$ divides both $d$ and $n/d$, hence
$$k^2 \ \mbox{ divides } n = d \cdot (n/d)$$
In particular $k \le \sqrt{x}$.

On the other hand, for arbitrary $k \le \sqrt{x}$ you have $(k,k,k^2) \in I_x$. This means that all numbers $k \le \sqrt{x}$ appear at least once as the first coordinate of a triple $(k,d,n) \in I_x$, while all numbers $k > \sqrt{x}$ don't.

So, let's call
$$g_x(k) = |\{ (d,n) \ : \ (k,d,n) \in I_x \}|$$
This function counts how many times $k$ appears as a first coordinate of a triple $(k,d,n) \in I_x$, so that
$$F(x)=  \sum_{(k,d,n) \in I_x} k=\sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{x}} g_x(k) \cdot k$$
To conclude the proof we have to show that
$$g_x(k) = 2 \lfloor \frac{x}{k^2} \rfloor-1$$

For a fixed $k \le \sqrt{x}$, you have that $(k,d,n) \in I_x$ if and only if $k= \gcd(d,n/d)$. This means that $d=ak$ and $n/d=bk$ for some $a,b$. Thus we can consider the set of quintuples
$$J_x= \{ (k,a,b,d,n) \ : \ d=ak, \ n/d=bk, \ \gcd(a,b)=1, \ d|n, \ n \le x \}$$
which is in clear bijection with $I_x$ by the map $(k,a,b,d,n) \mapsto (k,d,n)$.
Note that $a=d/k$ and $b=n/(dk)=n/(abk^2)$.
So that our $J_x$ is in bijection with the set
$$L_x = \{ (k, a, b) : \ abk^2 \le x , \ \gcd(a,b)=1\}$$
by the map $(k,a,b,d,n) \mapsto (k,a,b)$, because $n=abk^2 \le x$.
In other words
$g_x(k)$ counts the number of pairs $(a,b)$ of coprime numbers $a,b$ such that $abk^2 \le x$, or
$$ab \le \frac{x}{k^2}$$

continues...

OK, MY BAD, NOW I NOTICED THAT THIS NUMBER IS NOT $2 \lfloor \frac{x}{k^2} \rfloor-1$, BUT IT'S TRICKIER.
I'll leave this answer for who wants to conclude my computations.

Comment: Appears to be a very nice approach (+1)

Comment: $(k,k,k) \not\in I_x$. Perhaps you meant $(k,k,k^2)$?

Comment: Sorry guys, while I was writing the proof I noticed that my idea was good, but more complicated than I thought.

Answer (score 2):

It can be proved that $\displaystyle \sum_{d\mid n} (d,n/d) = \sum_{d^2\mid n}\tau(n/d^2)\varphi(d)$.

So one can show that $\displaystyle F(x) = \sum_{n\le \sqrt{x}}\varphi(n)\sum_{m \le x/n^2} \left\lfloor\frac{x}{n^2 m}\right\rfloor$.

This is the best i can do, but this is still computationally unfeasible for $x \approx 10^{15}$.

Comment: With this formula, my computer calculate $F(10^9)$ in about 13 minutes. Since it grows at least linearly, $x = 10^{15}$ is definitely out of range.

Comment: You have a typo in your formula for $F(x)$, it ought to be $$F(x) = \sum_{n \leqslant \sqrt{x}} \varphi(n) \sum_{m \leqslant x / n^2} \biggl\lfloor \frac{x}{m\cdot n^2}\biggr\rfloor\,.$$ And you can easily make that computationally feasible ($7$ seconds for $x = 10^{15}$ in not yet optimised C on my old laptop) using two tricks. First, don't compute $\varphi(n)$ for each $n$ separately, precompute all needed values in an array, similar to a sieve of Eratosthenes (takes $O(\sqrt{x})$ space and $O(\sqrt{x}\,\log \log x)$ time as long as you can use a builtin integer type).

Comment: (For $10^{15}$, 64-bit integers suffice.) Second, for the inner sum use Dirichlet's trick (hyperbola method), $$T(y) = \sum_{k \leqslant y} \tau(k) = \sum_{k \leqslant y} \biggl\lfloor \frac{y}{k}\biggr\rfloor = 2\sum_{k \leqslant \sqrt{y}} \biggl\lfloor \frac{y}{k}\biggr\rfloor - \lfloor \sqrt{y}\rfloor^2$$ to compute $T(y)$ in $O(\sqrt{y})$ time. That gives an overall time complexity of $$\sum_{n \leqslant \sqrt{x}} O\biggl(\sqrt{\frac{x}{n^2}}\biggr) = O\bigl(\sqrt{x}\,\log x\bigr)\,.$$ If that's not fast enough one can start to optimise.

Comment: @DanielFischer
Thank you, i corrected the typo.
Doh! how I forgot the Dirichlet's trick?!
That make it computationally feasible!

Comment: I kinda hoped you'd also include the algorithmic suggestions in your answer.